# Console Application Input Validation for Int & Float Max Values C#

Tags: c#, validation, console-application

I am building an application that takes two inputs from user. One int and the other float.
`int.MaxValue` and `float.MaxValue` are the two properties I am using to validate the input.

However, the input is built in such a way by adding each `KeyChar` because each key input has to be validated during Key press event as application restricts users to number (whole/decimal).

Here the code so far:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
const int intMaxValue = int.MaxValue;
const float floatMaxValue = float.MaxValue;
bool validated;
int tempAmount;
int intAmount;
string tempVal="";

do{
    key = Console.ReadKey (true);
    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {                    
       validated  = int.TryParse (key.KeyChar.ToString(), out tempAmount);
       if (validated)
       {
          ///Full amount is built here
          tempVal += key.KeyChar;
  //Fails here--->> as Type Cast happens on a String which hold a value beyond an int
          if (int.Parse(tempVal) < intMaxValue)
          {                    
             intAmount = int.Parse(tempVal);
             Console.Write(key.KeyChar);                         
          }
```

I could do this test after user has pressed Enter Key. However still it will be failed. Becuase there's no way an int could hold beyond its max Value..

Thus I came up with the following: However it doesn't feel efficient as my second input validation is based on `float`....

```
if (float.Parse(tempVal) < intMaxValue)
{
```

Therefore someone please show me an efficient property of int, float class that can be used in the two scenarios..
**OR** any other way to *sew* the input while validating each key digit by digit until user enters Enter key.

Comment: It is better to work with Console.ReadLine instead of ReadKey. You should react to your user input when he finishes.

Comment: What should happen when I right-click, past a word and hit enter? Why would you want to validate every keypress instead of the entire value? Just a question.

Comment: Appreciate your insights @Steve & Silvermind. If we look at WinForms or Web Forms, usually these objects are already set to the acceptable format. And those are validated by key. Plus I don't want to keep on displaying "Input is wrong, please enter valid data type"... :)

Comment: @Silvermind well, `Console` is not the same to `CMD`, right-clicking doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Steve I wish you had kept your code, so to accept it as answer, although I have a working code on similar concept. Because after hours of tackling the _single key_ validation, I realized why you had suggested `ReadLine` instead of `ReadKey`. I might not be having the same reason as of you, however my reason to switch back to `ReadLine` is mainly due to reading floats. When `ReadKey` was used, User had no way of validating it for float, there was more code lines in need, although it is not impossible. Thanks again.

Comment: All right, I was thinking that my answer was not really fit for your requirements so I have deleted it, but I will restore the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with ReadLine will be easier

```
bool validated = false;
int integerRequired;
Console.WriteLine("Type an integer number:");
while(validated == false)
{    
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    validated  = int.TryParse (userInput, out integerRequired);
    if (!validated )
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer, please retype a valid integer number");
}

float singleRequired;
validated = false;
Console.WriteLine("Type a floating point number:");
while(validated == false)
{    
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    validated  = Single.TryParse (userInput, out singleRequired);
    if (!validated)
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid float, please retype a valid float number");
}
```

In this example, you react to the user input only when he finishes to type and press enter. At this point you could evaluate the input using the version of TryParse appropriate for the input and choose to display or not an error message to the user.

Comment: I have the answer in this format already. Means, validating the full input by user. After building that, I wanted to test out for each key, as the console window was getting populated with so many Error Alerts. I appreciate your answer. But I would really want to know a better way to validate each key as well. Is there a performance drop for validating each key compared to above method? Or is there a C# language limitation going in that direction? Looking at your profile there must be a reason you suggested `ReadLine`..

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `TryParse`.
`TryParse` will evaluate to false if the value isn't a valid `Int32` (if will be false if it exceeds `Int32.MaxValue`).

```
int realValue;

if (Int32.TryParse(tempVal, out realValue))
   {                    
      intAmount = int.Parse(tempVal);
      Console.Write(key.KeyChar);                         
   }
```

You can also use the corresponding`float.TryParse` to test the float values you expect.

Comment: Apreciate your code. I voted up due to the direct easiness. After tackling for hours, I realized that there's no point validating each key, because when I hit floating input it breaks big time. Why? User should be able to input `2.5` sort of values for floating input. And If I am validating each key, that's not helping for this. Perhaps that's why @Steve mentioned it's good to read the full input then validate it. So I finally stick to it. But learnt alot about single input validation as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (validated)
   {
      ///Full amount is built here 
      long l = long.Parse(tempVal + key.KeyChar);        
      if (l < intMaxValue)
      {                    
         intAmount = (int)l;
         tempVal += key.KeyChar;
         Console.Write(key.KeyChar);                         
      }
```

However, as others suggested, you should use `Console.ReadLine` and use `TryParse` in combination with a `while` loop until the input is `validated`.

After some deeper scan into your code, I think yo don't need the `tempVal` when you already have `intAmount`, just do something like this:

```
 if (validated)
   {
      long k = intAmount*10L + (int) key.KeyChar - 48;
      if (k < intMaxValue)
      {                    
         intAmount = (int)k;
         Console.Write(key.KeyChar);                         
      }
```

Comment: Hi King King, it's great that C# has a limitation to its max data type for number :D otherwise I would have had to go after each of them. So to say, this is the same concept as what I have done in my code for int? no?

Comment: @aspiring yes, doing like you did will break the code when the `Key` is input so that the `int.Parse` fails, that's why I used `long.Parse` instead but **it will never fail with long** because you should **stop** user from inputting when it reaches the `intMaxValue` (of course, the `long.MaxValue` is never reached at that time). **However**, I have another solution for you in my second code, check it out.

Comment: You haven't seen my last line.. :) `if (float.Parse(tempVal) < intMaxValue)`

Comment: @aspiring your code in the last line can be compared to using `long`, I think it's OK, why do you think it's not efficient enough? Your `process` doesn't require much strictness in performance so it's OK. However it looks like you haven't checked out the second solution in my answer? It uses only `casting` from `long` to `int` and **doesn't** need `tempVal`.

Comment: King King, I switched back to my old code. Please see my comments to Steve and scartag.